# Which class method should I use for deprecated JDocumentRenderer->render();

Tags: module, joomla-api

I need to display a module in administrator side by getting the module using it's module position (see the code below). I am having error & doubt is using the code:

**`$renderer = $document->loadRenderer('module');`**

This `JDocumentRenderer` is not working in Joomla latest version 3.x. I also referred the [link](http://docs.joomla.org/Potential_backward_compatibility_issues_in_Joomla_3_and_Joomla_Platform_12.2):

> JDocumentRenderer does not extend JObject anymore. You must not use any of JObject's methods

But I need to render the module...

```
$modules = JModuleHelper::getModules("dashboard_main");
$document   = JFactory::getDocument();
$renderer   = $document->loadRenderer('module');
$attribs    = array();
$attribs['style'] = 'xhtml';

foreach($modules as $mod){

   // this code is not rendering the module
   echo $renderer->render($mod, $attribs);
 }
```

Answer (score 8):

Instead of `JDocumentRenderer` you should use `JModuleHelper` to render modules:

```
foreach($modules as $mod)
{
   echo JModuleHelper::renderModule($mod, $attribs);
}
```

See [renderModule()](https://github.com/joomla/joomla-cms/blob/master/libraries/cms/module/helper.php#L139) method.